# How to upgrade the Exim to version “4.92” on Ubuntu 18.04 server?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, mail-server, exim

A critical vulnerability ([CVE-2019-10149](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-10149)) was found in Exim mail server. It allows to execute some code on victim's server with root privileges. This vulnerability affects versions from 4.87 to 4.91.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server with Exim version 4.90_1 installed (but disabled) and I need to upgrade it to the version 4.92 - but I can't find how to do it properly through the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu releases do not receive 'major' or 'feature' updates for packages – you always have the same version you started with, and the packager just applies individual patches to fix bugs or security issues. (Use `apt-get changelog exim4` to see what changes are made.)

For Ubuntu 18.04, you need to upgrade the exim4 package to [4.90.1-1ubuntu1**.2**](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4_4.90.1-1ubuntu1.2/changelog), which is a security update that has a fix for CVE-2019-10149 applied, but doesn't include any other 4.92 stuff. If you did a full system upgrade recently, then you already have it.